# Trouble with compressed image transport and ardrone_autonomy

Tags: opencv, image-transport, ardrone-autonomy, compressed-image-transport, ardrone2.0

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recorded some .bag files from a few runs with the ardrone_autonomy node. I was recording the compressed image topic, and I can successfully play it back using image_view.

However, I tried putting together a simple node that would subscribe to the data. It looks like this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "detector_node");

  ros::Time::init();

  ros::NodeHandle nh;

  image_transport::ImageTransport it(nh);
  image_transport::Subscriber sub = it.subscribe("ardrone/front/image_raw", 1, imageCallback);

  ros::spin();

  return 0;
}
```

I then run the node as such:

`rosrun detector_node _image_transport:=compressed`

However, I get this error endlessly:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cvtColor, file /tmp/buildd/ros-groovy-opencv2-2.4.6-0precise-20130721-1609/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 3346
> [ERROR] [1379682592.318100441]: /tmp/buildd/ros-groovy-opencv2-2.4.6-0precise-20130721-1609/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:3346: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor`

Here's the output from rostopic info:

> Type: sensor_msgs/CompressedImage

> Publishers:
>
> - /play_1379682668712408406 (http://aramis:36403/)

> Subscribers:
>
> - /detector_node (http://aramis:35284/)

EDIT: When I run the drone live (i.e., not from a bag file), I get the same error. However, if I use the theora transport, it works fine.

EDIT: I'm using ROS Groovy on Ubuntu 12.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/81476/trouble-with-compressed-image-transport-and-ardrone_autonomy/) by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13689 on 2013-09-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe my issue for this was that I had a conflicting installation of OpenCV.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2015-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0